# How to determine if a stream is STDIN in PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm working on some PHP cli tools for a php framework and there's a situation where my script either reads from a file or `STDIN`. Since not all operations (like `fseek()`) are valid on `STDIN`, I'm looking for a way to detect this.

Comment: I don't understand.  Surely you must know whether you're passing `stdin` or a standard file to a particular function?  Do you mean you don't know whether `stdin` corresponds to a TTY or a file being piped in?

Comment: Since it doesn't matter if the data on `stdin` comes from a tty or a file regarding seeking abilities etc, I'm sure he doesn't want a PHP equivalent of `isatty()`. I guess he has a function which accepts an fd and he wants to make his code generic so it can work with both a regular file and stdin.

Comment: @ThiefMaster That's exactly it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the function `stream_get_meta_data()` provides a solution, when called on standard in, the result is:

```
array(9) {
  ["wrapper_type"]=>
  string(3) "PHP"
  ["stream_type"]=>
  string(5) "STDIO"
  ["mode"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["unread_bytes"]=>
  int(0)
  ["seekable"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["uri"]=>
  string(11) "php://stdin"
  ["timed_out"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["blocked"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["eof"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

So you can do a simple string compare on the uri:

```
function isSTDIN($stream) {
    $meta = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
    return strcmp($meta['uri'], 'php://stdin') == 0;
}
```

This solution will work whether the constant stream `STDIO` is used, or the old `fopen('php://stdin', 'r')`, which still lurks around in old code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check `if($fp === STDIN)`

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm working with legacy code that uses the older `fopen('php://stdin..` syntax, making the comparison fail. This should work if use the constant instead.